# Is it possible to find who made last update of a piece of code in svn

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, svn-repository

I want to check revision history of a particular piece of code using svn repository. It will be ok if I could just check who made the last update, i.e. who is responsible for a the current state of a piece of code. I can go through the revision histories for the entire file, but if I could do the same for just a portion of the file ( a block or method may be), that would be helpful. Is it possible using svn? or any other similar tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's possible.

```
svn blame <target>[@<revision>]
```

look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) for more details